# Spark job fail with zlib OverflowError

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, zlib

I'm using spark 1.5 (pyspark), Python Version 2.7.3, zlib version is 1.0  with the following configuration:

6 machines, 180 GB Ram each.

```
Spark-submit --master yarn --num-executors 10 --executor-memory 35G --driver-memory 6G
```

I'm having sometimes `OverflowError: size does not fit in an int` Exception and the job fails.

As i see this the exception is not related to my code but to spark mechanism to compress the data when moving the data from server to server.

I could not find any solution online but i tried to change the compression types but it did not help. I also tried to disable compression with setting to `false spark.rdd.compress, spark.shuffle.compress, spark.shuffle.spill.compress, spark.broadcast.compress` but it didn't help either. Is any work around? 
 Heres the stacktrace:

```
17/01/02 13:16:27 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 313.0 in stage 10.0 (TID 1532, server01.dom): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.6.0-1.cdh5.6.0.p0.45/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 111, in main
    process()
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.6.0-1.cdh5.6.0.p0.45/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 106, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.6.0-1.cdh5.6.0.p0.45/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2355, in pipeline_func
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.6.0-1.cdh5.6.0.p0.45/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2355, in pipeline_func
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.6.0-1.cdh5.6.0.p0.45/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2355, in pipeline_func
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.6.0-1.cdh5.6.0.p0.45/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2355, in pipeline_func
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.6.0-1.cdh5.6.0.p0.45/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2355, in pipeline_func
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.6.0-1.cdh5.6.0.p0.45/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2355, in pipeline_func
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.6.0-1.cdh5.6.0.p0.45/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 317, in func
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.6.0-1.cdh5.6.0.p0.45/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/rdd.py", line 1789, in _mergeCombiners
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.6.0-1.cdh5.6.0.p0.45/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/shuffle.py", line 317, in mergeCombiners
    self._spill()
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.6.0-1.cdh5.6.0.p0.45/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/shuffle.py", line 345, in _spill
    self.serializer.dump_stream([(k, v)], streams[h])
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.6.0-1.cdh5.6.0.p0.45/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 267, in dump_stream
    bytes = self.serializer.dumps(vs)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.6.0-1.cdh5.6.0.p0.45/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 487, in dumps
    return zlib.compress(self.serializer.dumps(obj), 1)
OverflowError: size does not fit in an int
```

Comment: what is the RAM size of the machines running spark? what is your spark-submit parameters (RAM, num-executors, num-cores, master, etc)?

Comment: 6 machines, 180 GB Ram each. Spark-submit --master yarn --num-executors 10 --executor-memory 35G --driver-memory 6G

Comment: What version of zlib?

Comment: Python 2.7.3, when i print zlib.__version__ its says 1.0

Comment: This looks more like a python serialization issue than a compression issue. What kind of python objects do you have? Any chance your python objects are huge?

Comment: How can i know their size?

Comment: What is the size of the input log? do you have relevant parts of your code which you can share?